# not able to change contents in container of HTML

Tags: python, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web.py

I am trying to create a webpage using web.py. I have created test.py which calls index.html. Index page has 2 tabs. I want only content to be change when I will click tabs.

when click Performance : "this is performance" to be printed in container.
when click on Book Library : "this is book library" to be printed in container.

test.py

```
import web
render = web.template.render('templates/')

urls = (
    '/', 'index',
    '/performance', 'performance',
        '/(js|css|images)/(.*)', 'static', 
)

class index:
    def GET(self):
        return render.index()

class performance:
    def GET(self):
        return render.index()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/testi.css">  


</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">TESTING</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="/performance" id="Performance">Performance</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="Library">Book Library</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>


<div class="container">
  <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
  <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).
  <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
</div>



<div id="footer" class="container">
<p>TEST</p>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom"><p>TEST</p>
        <div class="navbar-inner navbar-content-center">
            <p class="text-muted credit">Testing project <a href="www.google.com">Martin Bean</a> </p>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```